# scope in jquery ready function

Tags: jquery

```
var $target = $("#a");
$(document).ready(function() {

    $target.fadeOut('fast');
});
```

a is a list item. For some reason, it wont fade out when the variable is defined outside of $(document).ready(). I thought that if I defined $target in the global scope, I can access it inside a function.

Can you tell me the difference between defining it outside and inside the document.ready function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting the $target variable, the document is not loaded yet, you need to do that into "ready" function.

Try this 3 posibilities:

```
//with global variable.
var $target = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $target = $("#a");

    $target.fadeOut('fast');
});

//with local variable.
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $target = $("#a");

    $target.fadeOut('fast');
});

//without variable
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#a").fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that outside `$(document).ready(function(){})` the **DOM** is not completely loaded and when you are assigning `var $target = $("#a");`(outside `$(document).ready(function(){})`) then may be no `$("#a")`(element with `id` **'a'**) inside **DOM**.The `$(document).ready(function(){})` event fires when your html (DOM) is completely loaded.

Proper jquery code should look like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $target = $("#a");
  $target.fadeOut('fast');
});
```